# Safari rendering fixed-width css incorrectly

Tags: css, safari

On my websites where I have a fixed width container (width:985px;) I find that on a Safari 5.1.7 on windows 7, 64-bit, the rendered width of the container on screen is only about 80% of that width forcing the layout to break as not wide enough.

On another windows 7 (64 bit) machine with Safari 5.0.3, all is fine.
On both computers, things look fine in IE (various versions), Opera, firefox, and chrome. 
My CSS validates.
I did view on an IPad, and layout was fine.

Appreciate any thoughts, help, etc.
Thanks!

```
#wrapper {position: relative;margin: 0 auto;width: 960px; text-align:left;}
```

wrapper is simply the first div after body tag
Here is link to one site where renders improperly in safari 5.1.7 on windows.
    http://www.wingserv.com/

Comment: You need to post your problem code for us to even begin to help with this.

Comment: why closing? that's not the intent behind 'too localized'. this question has the potential of helping many, many users tackling a real issue.

Comment: apple dropped safari for windows. i don't think there is any significant amount of people using safari on windows anymore. so i wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: edited to add line of css and link to one site where behavior in safari on my one windows 7 system.

Comment: By any chance do you have the screen zoomed in at all one of the browsers?? Try hitting CTRL + 0 ( or Command + 0 on Mac ) to see if that doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: According to gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201301-201303, Safari 5.1 had a 1.67% share as of 3/2013. Not sure how much of that is Mac. Safari 5.1 was the last version of Safari available for Windows.

Comment: I have viewed this on 5.1.7 and it looks fine to me. I'm not sure why you have position:relative set on a div that takes the entire window. Normally you would do that if you had child divs that are using absolute positioning. That may not have impact, but I might try removing that setting.

Comment: also I noticed a setting in your body class font-size:100.01% ? I'm also not familiar with this little hack, but I might suggest you try 1.01em instead.

Comment: I tried both changing the body font setting and removing the relative (latter was needed earlier version, but should have removed when eliminated an absolute I had). Neither did anything to help. (I just tested locally, not on remote server). Based on the 1.67% share for this browser, and the fact that only 1 of 2 here on my local machines behaves this way; I don't think I'll waste any more time on this. Content is there, layout gets fouled up, but so be it. Thanks for the help.